# Openpyxl, Telegram. Выбор активного листа в цикле for

Tags: python, telegram, openpyxl, aiogram-3.x

С помощью openpyxl получаю файл(читаю его).
С помощью цикла получаю все наименования листов.
Далее делаю команду, по которой вывожу данные из листа

```
import openpyxl

from aiogram import Router, F
from aiogram.types import Message
from aiogram.filters import Command, CommandStart

from keyboards import reply, inline

router = Router()
wb = openpyxl.reader.excel.load_workbook(filename = "data/Inventarization 2023.xlsx", data_only = True)

for item in wb.sheetnames:
sheet = wb[item]

@router.message((F.text == item))
async def agent (message: Message):
print(sheet)
text = ""
for i in range (11, 312):
    text += f" № {sheet['B' + str(i)].value}\n Дата ввода: {sheet['C' + str(i)].value}\n✏️ Серийный номер: {sheet['D' + str(i)].value}\n Инвентарный номер: {sheet['E' + str(i)].value}\n Наименование: {sheet['F' + str(i)].value}\n Кабинет: {sheet['G' + str(i)].value}\n Примечание: {sheet['H' + str(i)].value}\n\n"
for x in range(0, len(text), 4096):
    mess = text[x: x + 4096]        
    await message.answer(mess)
```

Есть 2 проблемы.

1. Выводит всегда только последний лист, я пробовал добавлять команду в цикл, всё равно также, только последний лист. (У меня их там 30)
2. Если даже получится вывести все листы помощью команды, то как сделать выбору строк?
   В данный момент у меня вывод строк идёт с 11 по 312, но не в каждом листе есть 312 строк.

   ```
   for i in range (11, 312):
   ```

Comment: Самое интересно, что через print(sheet), он выводит все листы книги. Но как только ввожу команду, то он только последнее берёт. 
Если команду внести в цикл, то он на все команды выдаёт последний лист. В чём нюанс, пока понять не могу)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Оказалось намного проще.
openpyxl всё верно выдаёт и проходит цикл, но вот уже в aiogram есть нюанс.

```
sheet = wb[item]
```

Здесь в принципе почти всё верно, но вместо item нужно использовать метод от aiogram **message.text**.

```
sheet = wb[message.text]
```

Со вторым вопрос, есть метод у openpyxl max_row, можно использовать **wb.max_row**
Либо же уже через **sheet["A1:A+"]**, что означает по последней строке.